# Replacement part for glass balcony door

Tags: doors, glass, frame, aluminum, closer

I need to replace this part, but I do not know what it is called (see picture). It serves to limit the range of motion of an aluminum frame glass door. It is exposed when the door is open. When closed, it folds on top of the door and is completely hidden.

What is it, and where can I find one?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be a [concealed overhead door stop](https://www.google.com/#q=concealed+overhead+door+stop&tbm=shop). You might have to search around a bit to find the right style and size - if you know the manufacturer of the door you can try there to see if they sell replacement parts.